# docx4j PDF export ignores TextDirection

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, docx4j, export-to-pdf

I'm using latest docx4j (3.3.7) and generate table, which contains one cell with text rotated by 90 degrees. `docx` output is correct, but when exported to `pdf`, text in this cell isn't rotated, just regular left-to-right direction.

Same behaviour is with Plutext's commercial PDF Converter (enabled by default) and with `docx4j-export-fo`.

**How can I force text in table cell to rotate?**

Code I use to rotate text in tableCell (work fine in `docx`, ignored during `pdf` export):

```
TcPr tableCellProperties = tableCell.getTcPr();
if (tableCellProperties == null) {
    tableCellProperties = new TcPr();
    tableCell.setTcPr(tableCellProperties);
}
TextDirection td = new TextDirection();
td.setVal("tbRl");
tableCellProperties.setTextDirection(td);
```

I also tried this, with same effect:

```
TextDirection td = new TextDirection();
td.setVal("tbRl");
paragraph.setPPr(new PPr());
paragraph.getPPr().setTextDirection(td);
```

I'm exporting to PDF using method:

```
Docx4J.toPDF(wordprocessingMLPackage, fileOutputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XSL FO has the property reference-orientation, it should be possible to implement in docx4j-export-fo:

- https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/201306/msg00050.html
- [What does reference-orientation really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523020/what-does-reference-orientation-really-do)

**17 June 2018 edit**

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-export-FO/commit/3b2c7423c25fe73bb5a85d9aa8755cce6e1aca8e and https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/d8254cbf69d7bb3decaa94254946bd293c5d3ec0 implement this.

The result is imperfect, however;  testing the following XSL-FO with FOP 2.3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <layout-master-set
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
        xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml"
        xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing">
        <simple-page-master margin-bottom="12mm"
            margin-left="1in" margin-right="1in" margin-top="12mm"
            master-name="s1-simple" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm">
            <region-body column-count="1" column-gap="12mm"
                margin-bottom="36.0pt" margin-left="0mm" margin-right="0mm"
                margin-top="36.0pt" />
            <region-before extent="0.0pt"
                region-name="xsl-region-before-simple" />
            <region-after extent="0.0pt"
                region-name="xsl-region-after-simple" />
        </simple-page-master>
        <page-sequence-master master-name="s1">
            <repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <conditional-page-master-reference
                    master-reference="s1-simple" />
            </repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </page-sequence-master>
    </layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence force-page-count="no-force"
        id="section_s1" format="" master-reference="s1">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

            <fo:table border-bottom-color="#000000"
                border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt"
                border-collapse="collapse" border-left-color="#000000"
                border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="0.5pt"
                border-right-color="#000000" border-right-style="solid"
                border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-color="#000000"
                border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="0.5pt"
                display-align="before" start-indent="1.12in" table-layout="fixed"
                width="3.12in">
                <fo:table-column column-number="1"
                    column-width="3.12in" />
                <fo:table-body start-indent="0in">
                    <fo:table-row height="0.79in"
                        keep-together.within-page="always">
                        <fo:table-cell border-bottom-color="#000000"
                            border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt"
                            border-left-color="#000000" border-left-style="solid"
                            border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-color="#000000"
                            border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt"
                            border-top-color="#000000" border-top-style="solid"
                            border-top-width="0.5pt" padding-bottom="0mm"
                            padding-left="1.91mm" padding-right="1.91mm" padding-top="0mm">
                            <fo:block-container reference-orientation="90">
                                <block xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                                    font-size="11.0pt" line-height="100%" space-after="0in"
                                    start-indent="2mm">
                                    <inline font-family="Calibri">Bottom up</inline>
                                </block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row height="0.79in"
                        keep-together.within-page="always">
                        <fo:table-cell border-bottom-color="#000000"
                            border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt"
                            border-left-color="#000000" border-left-style="solid"
                            border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-color="#000000"
                            border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt"
                            border-top-color="#000000" border-top-style="solid"
                            border-top-width="0.5pt" padding-bottom="0mm"
                            padding-left="1.91mm" padding-right="1.91mm" padding-top="0mm">
                            <fo:block-container
                                reference-orientation="-90">
                                <block xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                                    font-size="11.0pt" line-height="100%" space-after="0in"
                                    start-indent="2mm">
                                    <inline font-family="Calibri">Top down</inline>
                                </block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
            <fo:block font-size="11.0pt" line-height="107%"
                space-after="0.11in" white-space-treatment="preserve">
            </fo:block>

        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

the text is rotated as expected, but in one case appears outside the cell.

See also [Rotated text in table cell rendered above cell not within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289702/rotated-text-in-table-cell-rendered-above-cell-not-within)

If you explore this further you may conclude some extra fo attributes are required, or that it is a bug in FOP. Please share your findings in a comment here.

As an aside, similar behaviour in XHTML output.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Is it possible to achieve with docx4j 3.3.7, or this feature is not implemented?

Comment: Not implemented in 3.3.7, my answer was intended to give you enough info to "scratch your itch".  Now implemented, but as per edits above, may need tweaking.

Comment: wow, thanks - didn't expect that! Just used github version in my project and TextDirection works. I got bug you mentioned, I'll try to fix it on my own.